# php IF OR format?

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

This works

```
If ($flag != 'u') { stuff.. }
```

This also works.

```
If ($id != 0) { stuff.. }
```

But these don't seem to work for me....

```
If ( ($flag != 'u') || ($id != 0) ) { stuff.. }
If ( ($flag != 'u') or ($id != 0) ) { stuff.. }
If ($flag != 'u') || ($id != 0) { stuff.. }
If ($flag != 'u') or ($id != 0) { stuff.. }
If ( $flag != 'u' || $id != 0 ) { stuff.. }
If ( $flag != 'u' or $id != 0 ) { stuff.. }
```

Any idea why? and what format should I use for this in PHP?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: why do you capitalise `if`?

Comment: @vinculis I want it to check if $flag is NOT 'u' and check if $id is NOT zero, and then do something. Basically it's working with 2 if statements at the moment, but I want it to be a single if statement.... Basically `if either thing, then do stuff`. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're more able and better equipped to answer your first question. Answer for your second question is: `go for readability`. If `stuff` is the same I find second example more readable.

Comment: @MarkoD It's not capitalised in my code. Must have been the browser or something.

Comment: @Cully post the _real_ code you have, not an example one

Comment: @MarkoD The real code is what I have shown (minus capitalisation of if). Anything else will just complicate it. I got both to work separately, just not together. At the moment one is commented out. They will work if nested, but that seems a stupid way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works. I tried this

```
<?php
$flag= u;
$id= 0;
if ( ($flag != 'u') || ($id != 0) ) 
      { 
          echo "Hi";
      }
?>
```

The code simple says `if $flag not equal to u` or `if $id not equals 0` then `echo hi` in page.

Is that your logic?

The problem might be in your logic I hope!

Comment: I want it to do exactly what you describe. This is why it drove me crazy. I tried again and that code will not work for me. It just runs what's inside no matter what `$flag` or `$id` are. I changed it to `if ( $flag != 'u' && $id != 0 )` and it's working now, so I'm not sure the logic there.